# Highcharts Highstock enabledThreshold feature not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts

I can't seem to make it so in Highstock's AreaSpline chart in ReactJS so that markers are only visible when there are less than x in the line.
I checked several fiddles and Highcharts is working with the exact same configuration.

Not working:
https://jsfiddle.net/0qybw7jt/

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/8uwvm1np/

The difference is found within the constructor `chart` vs `stockChart`

Comment: It seems that `markers.enabled` is `false` by default in Highstock (flaw in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.marker.enabled). If you set it to undefined (as it's required by `enabledThreshold`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.marker.enabledThreshold) it works just like in Highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

I had to explicitly set marker: enabled to undefined, see code:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: undefined, 
            enabledThreshold: 1,
          radius: 4
        }
      }
    },
```