# Highstock, True way of Get count of shown points after setExtreme (Zooming) - WITHOUT counting all data with MIN and MAX

Tags: javascript, highcharts, stock

Sure there is a way to count all of points that shown after zooming or any changing view and do reaction for that.

My target is in Highchart 7.2.0 **stockChart**, **IF** *"viewed points"* **x** *"radius of circles"*, gone more than **(>)** *"view-port pixels"*, i just hide them, or doing something special with points, because some of them are Special and still should be shown.

so i need :

1. HOW GET : **Count of points that JUST viewed now** (WITHOUT PUTTING A "FOR" TO ALL OF DATA's)

(I just think if there is no true way for it, it is better to i count svg objects instead of : *counting all of my data and using **isInside** with **min** and **max***)

2. The Best Events for : "**afterSetExtremes**" and "**events**:{**redraw**:" [Solved i think]

```
              events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(event) {
                      console.log(event.min);
                      console.log(event.max);
                  }
              }
```

3. How i turn them off [Solved i think]

```
                    if (chart.userOptions.plotOptions.line.marker.enabled) {
                        chart.userOptions.plotOptions.line.marker.enabled=false;
                        chart.update({
                            plotOptions: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled:false
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

4. If there is automatic way like "amchart" options that i just ask "**marker**: { enabled: **true**" (when no problem) and "**marker**: { enabled: **false**" when it is tight. [Solved i think]

Solved by this:

```
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled:undefined,
                    enabledThreshold: 4,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 4,
                },
            }
        }
```

It was like this :

> marker: {enabled:**true**,
>   enabledThreshold: 0, (By Default)

Should be :

> marker: {enabled:**undefined**,
>   enabledThreshold: **4**, (More than Zero)

Got help from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417034/7514010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It answered by @ppotaczek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995042/7514010) in the third comment by this link [jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1tLfaxu](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1tLfaxu) and also in GitHub issues : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12017

If need to get count of points that just viewed now (by using **afterSetExtremes** or **redraw** or **render** events) :

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                console.log(this.series[0].points.length)
            }
        }
    },
```

- **processedXData** can be used too instead of **points**
- points object have enough options like **isInside** :

```
this.series[0].points[0].isInsdie.
```

Because it is **possible** the first or last point **be not shown** and just affect the lines in line chart or in other type of chart be not shown because zooming in Y too.

and for just calculation where the extreme started you may need :

```
this.series[0].cropStart
```

and comparing that with your main data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to loop through the data and check `isInside` point property or point position. As an alternative you can overwrite `translate` method and count the number of visible points in the existing loop:

```
var counter;

(function(H) {
    H.Series.prototype.translate = function() {
        ...

        counter = 0;
        // Translate each point
        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            ...
            point.isInside =
                plotY !== undefined &&
                plotY >= 0 &&
                plotY <= yAxis.len && // #3519
                plotX >= 0 &&
                plotX <= xAxis.len;

            // CHANGE

            if (point.isInside) {
                counter++;
            }

            // CHANGE

            ...
        }
        series.closestPointRangePx = closestPointRangePx;
        H.fireEvent(this, 'afterTranslate');
    }

})(Highcharts)
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx1cj0at/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thanks, but it is exactly what i want to avoid from that, because i think there should be a better way. like: **aftersetExtreme**, we get one of the childs of **event** or **this** and easily we can have that.

Comment: The `translate` method is called under the hood anyway. That solution only counts iterations - you don't have to create an additional loop. I don't see a more efficient solution at the moment.

Comment: Correction - for series types which require sorted data you can check `series.processedXData`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1tLfaxu/

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek
the true way is almost that. but with your permission i answer it full to my question.